# Is it possible to see an object's construction location in a JavaScript debugger?

Tags: javascript, debugging, parallel-processing, trace

Is it possible to see where an object was created/constructed/instantiated, when stepping through code in a JavaScript debugger (e.g. Chrome's DevTools, or Firefox's Firebug)? This is useful in applications that involve parallel paths (and hence tracing the call stack, does not necessarily bring you to the object's construction location).

I am currently solving this problem by forwarding and appending to a trace variable with each function call, but I was hoping that there was an easier, more elegant way to do this.

Comment: No, but if you restrict yourself to using `new` for creating objects, then `obj.constructor.name` will give you the name of the constructor function.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't tell you on which line (and file) that `new` was called.